# GUI depends on language and platform?

Tags: user-interface, platform

This is not a programming question but its more general. I have worked with lot of gui libraries to develop Pc/Mobile applications. Like cocoa for mac and iphone developemnt, .net libraries for c#, qt for c++. In an nutshell using of library depends on the language,developing  platform and target platform.
Now my question: does that mean we have to choose language and platform according to GUI we want to build? for eg, I like the GUI and GUI componenents(their visual appearence) of the mac the most. Then should I use objective c and mac platform? If I want good looking GUI then should I choose language and platform according to that?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

> does that mean we have to choose language and platform according to GUI we want to build?

Yes, the language and the platform you are targeting are the first things you have to choose. Unfortunately there's no universal language that will give you great looking GUIs among all platforms. Probably that's one of the reasons why internet web sites developed so much. Because as long as you have a capable browser running on your device the site will work.